# grunt-uncss with MEANJS project

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to run [grunt-uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) over a MEANjs project

in my grunt file I have the following :

```
 uncss:{
            dist:{
              options:{
                 urls:['http://localhost:3000']
              },
              files:{
               // 'public/dist/application1.min.css' : ['app/views/layout.server.view.html']              
                'public/dist/application1.min.css' : [''] 
              } 
            } 
         }
```

I get the following:

```
Running "uncss:dist" (uncss) task
[D] Task source: /home/arw201/code/gitLocal/testeo/clone3/node_modules/grunt-uncss/tasks/uncss.js
Warning: must provide pattern Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

I have the following dir structure

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── models
│   └── views/
        ├── 404.server.view.html
        ├── 500.server.view.html
        ├── index.server.view.html
        └── layout.server.view.html
├── bower.json
├── config
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── env
│   ├── express.js
│   ├── init.js
│   └── strategies
├── gruntfile.js
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── Procfile
├── public
│   ├── application.js
│   ├── config.js
├── content
│   └── style.css
├── dist
│   ├── application.min.css
│   └── application.min.js
│   
│   
├── README.md
└── server.js
```

this is part of the header in my  layout.view.html file

```
</head>

    <!--Application CSS Files-->
    {% for cssFile in cssFiles %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{cssFile}}">
    {% endfor %}
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
```

as you can see the css  is done dynamically, so for this I have to use the url option, otherwise I get other errors, I presume because of the dynamic nature of the css links.

The idea is to remove the all the css not being used by the application like for example the one from bootstrap.

so any help as to how can this be done is greatly appreaciated?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to forget about your approach embedding the css. You can make use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml

Furthermore, as far as I can say, you should consider to use a plain index.html for your angular application.